# Bash truncates long PS4 strings

Tags: bash, debugging

I am trying to debug a large build project which calls a bunch of bash scripts. Someone suggested modifying `PS4` so I set it to the following snippet in order to print the path of the script and the line number being executed.

```bash
export PS4='\e[33m+ ${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO} \e[0m'
```

However, when `BASH_SOURCE` was long, I noticed that all outputs were yellow (because of `\e[33m`). Upon further examination, I figured out that bash was truncating `PS4` whenever it was longer than about 80 chars or so and in such cases `\e[0m` never got executed. I googled a bit but I didn't find any documentation on this behaviour.

For now my only workaround is to truncate `BASH_SOURCE` manually. Is there a better way?

```bash
export PS4='\e[33m+ ${BASH_SOURCE:${#BASH_SOURCE}<80?0:-80}:${LINENO} \e[0m'
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the effect you are mentioning, but does wrapping the non-printing escape codes in `\[...\]` as described in the "PROMPTING" section of the manual help? Also, there is no need to export `PS4`.

Comment: Try creating a directory with say 100 chars. I just checked and I can reproduce. Wrapping non-printing escape codes doesn't help.